# MySQL query index

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, query-optimization

I am using MySQL 5.6 and try to optimize next query:

```
SELECT t1.field1,
       ...
       t1.field30,
       t2.field1
FROM Table1 t1
         JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.fk_int = t2.pk_int
WHERE t1.int_field = ?
  AND t1.enum_filed != 'value'
ORDER BY t1.created_datetime desc;
```

A response can contain millions of records and every row consists of 31 columns.

Now EXPLAIN says in Extra that planner uses 'Using where'.

I tried to add next index:

```
create index test_idx ON Table1 (int_field, enum_filed, created_datetime, fk_int);
```

After that EXPLAIN says in Extra that planner uses "Using index condition; Using filesort"

"rows" value from EXPLAIN with index is less than without it. But in practice time of execution is longer.

So, the questions are next:

1. What is the best index for this query?
2. Why EXPLAIN says that 'key_len' of query with index is 5. Shouldn't it be 4+1+8+4=17?
3. Should the fields from ORDER BY be in index?
4. Should the fields from JOIN be in index?

Comment: *What is the best index for this query?* Test `(int_field, enum_filed, fk_int, created_datetime)` and `(int_field, fk_int, enum_filed, created_datetime)`. *Why EXPLAIN says that 'key_len' of query with index is 5. Shouldn't it be 4+1+8+4=17?* Only first 2 columns in the index expression are used. *Now EXPLAIN says in Extra that planner uses 'Using where'* Filesort is present too, but not mentioned.

Comment: MySQL 5.6, first released nine years ago, reached end-of-life in February 2021, for what it's worth.  If you're going to put a lot of work into optimizing your app, you'd be wise to do that work with a current version of the software.

Comment: How many different values does `enum_filed` have?  (In case you have not noticed, several questions being thrown at you would be satisfied by providing `SHOW CREATE TABLE`)

Comment: When it says "5" for an `INT`, that's a clue that _maybe_ it should be `NOT NULL`.

Comment: @RickJames `enum_filed` has 5 different values.

Comment: @O.Jones, totally agree with you. But unfortunately I can not migrate for newest one for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was fixed by adding more filters (to `where` clause) to the query.
Regarding to indexes 2 proposed indexes were helpful:

1. From @WalterTross with next index for initial query:

`(int_field, created_datetime desc, enum_filed, fk_int)`

With my short comment: desc indexes is not supported at MySQL 5.6 - this key word just reserved.

2. From @RickJames with next index for modified query:

`(int_field, created_datetime)`

Thanks everyone who tried to help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

try refactor  your index this way
avoid (o move to the right after fk_int)  the created_datetime column.. and move fk_int before the enum_filed column .. the in this wahy the 3 more colums used for filter shold be use better   )

```
create index test_idx ON Table1 (int_field, fk_int, enum_filed);
```

be sure you have also  an specific index on  table2 column pk_int. if you have not  add

```
create index test_idx ON Table2 (int_field, fk_int, enum_filed);
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess for your question № 1:

```
create index my_idx on Table1(int_field, created_datetime desc, fk_int)
```

or one of these (but neither will probably be worthwhile):

```
create index my_idx on Table1(int_field, created_datetime desc, enum_filed, fk_int)
```

```
create index my_idx on Table1(int_field, created_datetime desc, fk_int, enum_filed)
```

I'm supposing 3 things:

- `Table2.pk_int` is already a primary key, judging by the name
- The `where` condition on `Table1.int_field` is only satisfied by a small subset of `Table1`
- The inequality on `Table1.enum_filed` (I would fix the typo, if I were you) only excludes a small subset of `Table1`

Question № 2: the `key_len` refers to the keys used. Don't forget that there is one extra byte for nullable keys. In your case, if `int_field` is nullable, it means that this is the only key used, otherwise both `int_field` and `enum_filed` are used.

As for questions 3 and 4: If, as I suppose, it's more efficient to start the query plan from the `where` condition on `Table1.int_field`, the composite index, in this case also with the correct sort order (`desc`), enables a scan of the index to get the output rows in the correct order, without an extra sort step. Furthermore, adding also `fk_int` to the index makes the retrieval of any record of `Table1` unnecessary *unless* a corresponding record is present in `Table2`. For a similar reason you could also add `enum_filed` to the index, but, if this doesn't considerably reduce the output record count, the increase in index size will make things worse instead of better. In the end, you will have to try it out (with realistic data!).

Note that if you put another column between `int_field` and `created_datetime` in the index, the index won't provide the `created_datetime` (for a given `int_field`) in the desired output order.

Answer (score 0):

What is the best index for this query?

- Maybe `(int_field, created_datetime)`  (See next Q&A for reason.)

Why EXPLAIN says that 'key_len' of query with index is 5. Shouldn't it be 4+1+8+4=17?

- `enum_filed !=` defeats the optimizer.  If there is only one other value for that enum (and it is `NOT NULL`), then use `=` and the other value.  And try `INDEX(int_field, enum_field, created_datetime)`  The Optimizer is much happier with `=` than with any inequality.
- "5" could be indicating 2 columns, or it could be indicating one `INT` that is Nullable.  If `int_field` can be `NULL`, consider changing it to `NOT NULL`; then the "5" would drop to "4".

Should the fields from ORDER BY be in index?

- Only if the index can completely handle the `WHERE`.  This usually occurs only if all the `WHERE` tests are `=`.  (Hence, my previous answer.)
- Another case for including those columns is "covering"; see next Q&A.

Should the fields from JOIN be in index?

- It depends.  One thing that gives *some* performance benefit is to include *all* columns mentioned *anywhere* in the `SELECT`.  This is called a "covering" index and is indicated in `EXPLAIN` by `Using index` (not `Using index condition`).  There are too many columns in t1 to add a "covering" index.  I think the practical limit is about 5 columns.